# Convergence of random variables $X_{n}=e^{n\alpha}1_{[n,\infty)}$ in specific probability space proof

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

Suppose $(\Omega, F, P)$ is probability space, where $\Omega =[0, \infty)$, $F$ is Borel $\sigma-$ algebra on $[0, \infty)$ and $P$ probability $P(B)=\int_{B}^{} e^{-x} \,dx, \forall B \in F$. Let's $(X_{n})_{n}$ be series of random variables $X_{n}=e^{n\alpha}1_{[n,\infty)}$. Show that for $\alpha < 1$ exists random variable X such that it is $X_{n} \rightarrow X$ in $L^{1}$.
$E(X_{n})=\int_{n}^{\infty} e^{-x}e^{n\alpha} \,dx=...=e^{n(\alpha-1)}$. Therefore, because $\alpha <1$ we have $\lim_{n\to\infty} E(X_{n})=0 $. Because of that: $\lim_{n\to\infty} (E(X_{n})-E(X))=0-EX=-EX $ and we can conclude that exists random variable X, for which it is $EX=0$, and $X_{n} \rightarrow X$ in $L^{1}$. I hope that proof is correct :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $X=0$ and conclude that $E|X_n-X| \to 0$ to finish the proof. Your argument does not make sense since  you did not  specify your $X$. [Th problem says show the existence of an $X$ and you have to say what $X$ is].

BTW, not every $X$ with $EX=0$ will  work. $X_n \to X$ in $L^{1}$ means $E|X_n-X |\to 0$ (not $E(X_n-X) \to 0$) and this can hold only for $X=0$.